# Gas equation problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I have been trying to solve this for hours without success. This is a problem: iron bottle (volume is equal $3\,\mathrm{dm^3}$) is filled with oxygen at the temperature of $310\,\mathrm{K}$ and with a pressure of $10^5\,\mathrm{Pa}$. The gas is heated to $410\,\mathrm{K}$ with the valve open. After that the valve closes and the gas is cooling down to its initial temperature. What is the pressure after cooling and what is the mass of the oxygen left in the bottle?

I wrote gas equation for each of the 3 states:
$$ p_1V = m_1RT_1/M, $$
$$ p_2V = m_2RT_2/M, $$
$$ p_3V = m_2RT_1/M. $$

From the first equation I can get $m_1$, but I'm stuck with 3 equations with 4 variables. I can't combine them properly to solve the problem.

I thought that $p_1 = p_2$ because the bottle is open. If that is the case then I can solve it.

Question: Is the pressure the same after heating? If not, do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. Please note, that this site has MathJax enabled and that you can typeset equations using $\LaTeX$ syntax (I have edited your question to use MathJax, click the edit button to see the source code). Further, this question falls under our definition of "homework-like" and as such therefore should have the "homework-and-exercise" tag.

Comment: I understand. I will use mathjax next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if I understand the question correctly, the pressure of the gas at both state 1 and 2 is equal to the ambient pressure (in this case, $10^5\:\mathrm{Pa}$ is atmospheric pressure, which totally makes sense). You might think of it as follows: if the pressure of the gas is higher than the ambient pressure while the valve is still open, the gas will go out of the bottle until the pressure drops down to the ambient pressure.

Comment: Thnk you so much for the superfast answer. Now it is easy to solve it.